# SparseAdam produces dimension error when inputing empty features

Tags: pytorch

```py
from torch import nn,optim
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable

def cumsum_1d_with_zero(input: torch.Tensor, include_last: bool = False) -> torch.Tensor:
    output = torch.zeros(input.size(0) + 1, dtype=input.dtype)
    torch.cumsum(input, 0, out=output[1:])
    if include_last:
        return output
    else:
        return output[:-1]

class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.EmbeddingBag(4, 300, sparse=True, mode='sum')
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(300, 1)
        self.optimizer = optim.SparseAdam(self.embedding.parameters(), 0.0001)
        self.dense_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.linear1.parameters(), 0.0001)
    def forward(self,inputs):
        rows = [torch.tensor(input, dtype=torch.int64) for input in inputs]
        lengths = torch.tensor([x.size(0) for x in rows], dtype=torch.int64)
        offsets = cumsum_1d_with_zero(lengths)
        indices = torch.cat(rows)
        embedding_res = self.embedding(indices, offsets)
        print(embedding_res)
        logits = F.sigmoid(self.linear1(embedding_res))
        return logits

    def optimize(self, logits):
        labels = Variable(torch.LongTensor([0, 1, 0, 1]).reshape(4,1).float())
        criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        loss = criterion(logits, labels)
        print(loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.dense_optimizer.step()

model = MyModel()
inputs = [[],[],[],[]]
result = model(inputs)
model.optimize(result)
```

When I run above code in cpu mode on torch1.8.2 version, I get the following error:

[image]

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (300) must match the size of tensor b (0) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Can someone help me understand this error ? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks,the above code is for reproduce. Just run and the bug would occur.